# How we Concatenate Two spitted array

Tags: python, arrays, split

Let say we have array x

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 3, 2, 1])
x1, x2, x3 = np.split(x, [3, 6])
```

I want to use append this two splited array let say x1 and x2 I want to Concatenate like [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
If I am using for Concatenate

```
x4 = x1+x3
x4
```

We are getting error like 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

What we can do for Concatenation two splited array . can you please help me with this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`+` is element-wise addition for numpy arrays. I guess you are looking for `np.concatenate`.

```
>>> np.concatenate([x1, x2])                                                    
array([ 1,  2,  3, 99, 99])
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. like wise if we are discard/subtract  bigger array with smaller array then what we can do for this situation example  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  - [4,5] = [1,2,3,4] , what we can do for this

Comment: @LalatenduJena why is there a `4` in the result?

Comment: yes sorry for typing mistake it'ts [1,2,3] only

Comment: @LalatenduJena there's no builtin function to do that, you'd have to write some custom logic.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response .... I will try to write built in function for this

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to get desired result:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 3, 2, 1])
x1, x2, x3 = np.split(x, [3, 6])
x4 = np.hstack((x1, x3))
print(x4)  # [1 2 3 2 1]
```

`hstack` stands for horizontal stack, there also exist `vstack` for vertical stack, these functions can be also used with multidimensional arrays.